# Getting data from Custom EditText fields when click on button

Tags: android

I have created a custom `EditText` . Now the problem is I don't know how to get data from this `EditText` when user clicks on button.

Here's the Login.xml code

```
<com.amar.MyCustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/etmob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your Mobile no"
            android:phoneNumber="true">
 </com.amar.MyCustomEditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/submit" />.
```

And this is my java code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmob);
            String mobileno = et.getText().toString();
            if(mobileno == 1234567890)
           {
            Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Verify.class);
               startActivity(iv);
           }
             }
    });
```

And this is MyCustomEditText.java

```
        public class MyCustomEditText extends EditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

public MyCustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    // define the style of line
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    // define the color of line
    mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#B1B0B0"));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = getHeight();
    int lHeight = getLineHeight();
    // the number of line
    int count = height / lHeight;
    if (getLineCount() > count) {
        // for long text with scrolling
        count = getLineCount();
    }
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;

    // first line
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

    // draw the remaining lines.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 10, r.right, baseline + 10,
                paint);
        // next line
        baseline += getLineHeight();
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
  }
```

Comment: this line   `if(mobileno == 1234567890)` makes not your code  compile. Post the code you are using describing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, you are not initializing your own custom `Edittext`, you are using Android default `Edittext`.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            com.amar.MyCustomEditText et = (com.amar.MyCustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.etmob);
            String mobileno = et.getText().toString();
            if(mobileno.equalsIgnoreCase("1234567890"))
           {
            Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Verify.class);
               startActivity(iv);
           }
             }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyCustomEditText _et = (MyCustomEditText)findviewbyid(R.id.etmob);
String _enteredvalue = _et.gettext.tostring();
sysyem.out.println(_enteredvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

**please try with**

```
MyCustomEditText editText = (MyCustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.etmob);
String mobileno = editText.getText().toString();
if(mobileno.equalsIgnoreCase("1234567890"))
{
...
}
```

**code**

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyCustomEditText et = (MyCustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.etmob);
            String mobileno = et.getText().toString();
            if(mobileno.equalsIgnoreCase("1234567890"))
           {
            Intent iv = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Verify.class);
               startActivity(iv);
           }
             }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
MyCustomEditText editText = (MyCustomEditText)findViewById(id of the view);
String value = editText.getText().toString();
if(value=="1234567890"){
           //ToDo something
 }else{
           //ToDo something
 }
```